# Three JS scene not rendering triangle

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm very new to Three.JS, and I'm simply just trying to create a single triangle in the scene, but for some reason it is not being rendered. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/mi496949/qvvzckh2/

```
/*global THREE, requestAnimationFrame*/

var scene, camera, renderer, scene, controls, canvasWidth, canvasHeight;

canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;

function onWindowResize(event) {
  'use strict';
  camera.aspect = canvasWidth / canvasHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
}

function randomColor() {
  'use strict';
  var color = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' +
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ')';

  return (new THREE.Color(color));
}

function init() {
  'use strict';
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, canvasWidth / canvasHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  scene.add(camera);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor(0xccccff);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function animate() {
  'use strict';
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function createTriangle() {
  'use strict';
  var centerPoint, point1, point2, triangleGeometry, triangle, angle, length1, length2;

  angle = (2 * Math.PI) / 100;

  length1 = 450;
  length2 = Math.tan(angle / 2) * length1;

  triangleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

  triangleGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  triangleGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-length2, length1, 0));
  triangleGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(length2, length1, 0));

  triangleGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));

  triangle = new THREE.Mesh(triangleGeometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());

  scene.add(triangle);
}

init();
createTriangle();
animate();
```

I apologize beforehand if it turns out to be something stupid and simple that I missed. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things in your code that need to be fixed so you can see the triangle:

First you need to set the camera away from the triangle. Since your triangle is drawn in the XY plane, lets move it away on the Z axis:

```js
camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);
```

Then you need to increase the `far` property of the camera so your triangle is inside the camera frustum. Since the camera is 1000 units away from the triangle, let's give it some room and place the `far` plane 2000 units away.

```js
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, canvasWidth / canvasHeight, 1, 2000);
```

The last thing that you need to do is to change the order in which you have added the vertices to the face. Right now the order `(0, 1, 2)` creates a face in clockwise order, with its normal vector pointing down (-Z) because Three.js follows the [right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule). If you change the order to `(1, 0, 2)`, the vertices' order will be counterclokwise, the face's normal will point towards the camera (+Z), and you will be able to see it.

```js
triangleGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1, 0, 2));
```

An alternative to changing the vertices' order would be to change the `side` property of the material to `THREE.DoubleSide` so you can see both sides of the face and not just the one with the normal pointing at the camera:

```js
triangle = new THREE.Mesh(triangleGeometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide}));
```

You can see a working example with your code in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8c34dnfy/).

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful and insightful.